# ClassNotFoundException problem outside Eclipse

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I'm having problems running my application outside Eclipse, because when I try this runtime exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javazoom/jl/player/Player
    at InterruptHandler$1.execute(InterruptHandler.java:22)
    at InterruptHandler.run(InterruptHandler.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javazoom.jl.player.Player
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 3 more
```

As you can probably conclude from the exception, I'm using JLayer, which I use to play some MP3 files. Of course my first conclusion was the classpath. However, I've now tried numerous different classpath options, however this exact exception has been thrown on my every attempt.
Note that all of the .class files reside in a 'bin' directory in the default package, and amongst all of those .class files my .jar file is as well. Here's what classpath options I've tried (by the way, I'm on OS X):

```
java -classpath /Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin Game
java -classpath /Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin/jl.jar
java -classpath jl.jar Game
java -classpath *.jar Game
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
java -classpath /Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin/jl.jar:/Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin Game
```

...to pick up your .jar file as well as any of the miscellaneous .class files you have in the bin directory.

**EDIT:** Updated classpath to use `:` separator per comment from @Angel O'Sphere, as OP is using a Mac.

Comment: Well, that prints out every available runtime option, and tells me that /Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin is a directory...

Comment: Where does Game.class live? I would expect that output if you missed the "Game" off the end of that command.

Comment: Default package. Same as all other classes and jl.jar.

Comment: Just out of interest, what do you get if you do: `java -classpath /Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin/jl.jar Game`

Comment: Here's the command that works: java Game -classpath /Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin/jl.jar:/Users/b-dahse/Documents/workspace/project/bin<br/>But still this exception:<br/>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javazoom/jl/player/Player
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javazoom.jl.player.Player
Sorry I had to strip down the exception and the overall message, but the stupid max character thing made it a necessity.

Comment: That gives me this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Game
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Game
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Obviously you are on a Mac ;D so use ":" instead of ";" to seperate your classpath items.

Comment: @Angel - Well, I've learned something today. :) Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Using ":" is the "normal" path seperator on all Unix like systems, only windws uses ";" for PATH and CLASSPATH etc.

Answer (score 0):

Open Tomcat launch configuration and add jl1 jar in classpath . Restart your server and the problem resolved for me.